# A continuous real valued function that maps open sets to open sets are must be monotone

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ be a continuous function . $f$  maps open sets to open sets then prove that  $f$  must be  monotonic.

Now if I take $(0,1)\cup (3,4)$ such that  and  $f$  linearly maps $(0,1)$ increasingly to $(5,6)$  and $(3,4)$  decreasingly  onto $(6,5)$(I did not know how else to write this , hope you people understand) i.e.  $$f((0,1)\cup (3,4))=(5,6)$$ then $f$ satisfies the given criteria without being monotone . So ,I guess it should have been "*intervals*"  instead  of "*sets*". In that  case , I need  some hints as to how to begin the proof.

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb{R}$. You can't "take $(0,1) \cup (3,4)$" as the domain.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo : Why $?$

Comment: Because the domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo : Sorry I'll  edit . What I meant was that $f$  takes  $(0,1)\cup (3,4)$  to $(5,6)$  like *open set* to *open set*.

Comment: @pGroups : Huh $?$

Comment: @user118494 You did not understand my point. Unless you specify what $f$ is supposed to be outside of $(0,1) \cup (3,4)$, that function you defined is irrelevant to the discussion, since it is not a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For general interest: The logical error is in assuming that if you find a non-monotone $f$ that maps *an* open set to another open set, that violates the proposition.  But in order to invalidate the proposition, you must find a non-monotone $f$ that maps *all* open sets to open sets. If $f$ has a local maximum or minimum, however, that won't be possible.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: I don't think that's at issue, for if we define $f(x) = 7-|x-2|$, then we find that the function does what OP says it does in the specified intervals.  But the problem is that the condition is not satisfied for $f$, since there exist open sets, such as $(1, 3)$, that map onto non-open sets (in this case, $(6, 7]$).

Comment: @BrianTung That is the issue. He presents the function as being a counter-example to the statement, which it isn't, because you must define it outside the set also, and the moment you do the function is not an open mapping anymore.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: OK.  I do not think we disagree in substance.  My observation was simply that the function not being completely defined on $\mathbb{R}$ was not at issue; it was the notion that there existing an open set that mapped (via a non-monotonic function) to another open set falsified the proposition.  That is not true; one needs all open sets to map to open sets.  Of course, as you point out, the moment one fully defines such an $f$ (i.e., continuous and non-monotonic), one can identify an open set that does not map to an open set.  As I say, I don't think we disagree in substance.

Answer (score 3):

The statement you need to prove is correct: it applies to open sets in general, not just intervals. Here's a hint on how to proceed:

Consider the case where $f$ is not monotonic. That means it must have a local maximum/minimum at a point, say, $x_0$. Consider a small open interval that contains $x_0$. What can you say about its image under $f$?

Comment: It  will be a  semi closed interval . So is  that  it  . Proof   done $?$

Comment: yes that's all there is to it. In other words if f is not monotonic, there exist a,b with a < b, such that for some c in (a , b),  the value f(c) does not lie in the closed interval whose endpoints are f(a), f(b). So  some point in (a,b) is a local extremum of f.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ isn't monotonic, then it has a local maximum or a local minimum. (We need continuity here; otherwise consider $f(x) = \chi_\mathbb{Q}(x) x$. The completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ is also important: the function $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ given by $x^3 - 6x$ is continuous, non-monotonic, and has no local extrema.) The argument is symmetric, so let's assume $f$ has a local maximum at $x$. Thus there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(y) \leq f(x)$ for all $y \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$. But then $f(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ isn't open, for it contains the point $f(x)$, which isn't an interior point.